# Android Spinner Itemselected method not fired

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, spinner

I've got this Android application build in C#
There are a few spinners on the layout, on which ItemSelected methods are attached. For some reason the methods are not fired when I select an item

This is my code, which is pretty standard.

```
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            InitializeLocationManager();

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            cit = (Spinner)FindViewById(Resource.Id.city1);
            cit.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(spinner_ItemSelected1_city);
            str = (Spinner)FindViewById(Resource.Id.street1);
            str.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(spinner_ItemSelected1_street);
}
```

The first spinner's adapter is filled with data from a file. The second spinner's adapter is filled with data based on the selected item from the first. Unfortunately the ItemSelected method of the first spinner is not fired, thus the second spinner's adapter is not populated.
The selected item is also not visible in the spinner box. However when I open the first spinner again the previous selected item is on top.

I did set a breakpoint at the first spinners ItemSelected eventhandler to see what happens while debugging, but that breakpoint is not triggered, so to my understanding the method is not fired.

**EDIT**

I did notice some strange behavior. When I launch the application on my Android phone, the same happens as described above.
But when I open another app on my phone, and then go back to the above application, it's works as expected...

Hopefully someone can explain this behavior, cause I'm a bit lost now